Uniqueness of the solution to switching coefficient SDEs
Consider the following SDE driven by real-valued Brownian motion $W=(W_t)_{t\ge 0}$:
$$dX_t = \left(\sigma {\bf 1}_{\{X_t>1\}} + \sigma' {\bf 1}_{\{0<X_t\le 1\}}\right)dW_t,\quad \forall t>0,$$
where $\sigma,\sigma'>0$ are two different real numbers. Does the above SDE admit a unique pathwise solution? If so, can we extend the uniqueness result for

time dependent diffusion coefficients $\sigma(t), \sigma'(t)$?
space dependent diffusion coefficients $\sigma(x), \sigma'(x)$?

